# Magento 2.3.2 Failed to load the "Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message" component

Tags: cart, error, magento2.3.2, gift-card, giftmessage

On cart page I am receiving this error in console:

> Failed to load the "Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message"
>   component

***Applied coupon code "test123" not showing in cart page summary**.

However the subtotal showing correct with deducted of discount amount*.

I have disabled 3rd party modules one by one. Still no change. Maybe this error is responsible to not display Discount amount in cart page summary.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error in console
[ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message" component.

Answer (score 0):

I have applied below code as I have to also move it to "checkout.cart.shipping"

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" 
 name="checkout.cart.coupon2" as="coupon" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml"/>
    <move element="checkout.cart.coupon2" destination="cart.summary" before="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
```